# Disable tooltip for specific series in multiBarHorizontalChart

Tags: d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

Is there some way to disable tooltip for specific series in multiBarHorizontalChart?

I've found this link below on the nvd3 docs, but it seems that it only works for LineChart charts.

https://github.com/novus/nvd3/wiki/Data-Attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including `.tooltips(false)`.

Check this out http://nvd3.org/examples/multiBarHorizontal.html

Comment: I tried the `.tooltips(false)` option, but this turn off all the tooltips from the chart. What i need is disable the tooltips for only one of the series that i have on my multiBarHorizontal chart.